# Collecting CSV/EXML file from a website that uses Javascript

Tags: python, web-scraping

As a beginner I've been heavily warned to avoid resource heavy browsers for web scraping such as Selenium.

Then I looked at this site: [Intcomex Webstore](http://store.intcomex.com/en-XUS/Products/ByCategory/cpt.allone?r=True)

My idea was to make an alert program to tell me the price and if the item was low in quantity.

I can't for the life of me figure out how one would even attempt to get any of this information, whether through the CSV/EXML files or directly.

I'd possibly use `requests` however it only returns the javascript function as a link: `href="javascript:PriceListExportCSV('/en-XUS/Products/Csv','query‌​');`

In Developer Tools after I've clicked the CSV link I see a GET request to `http://store.intcomex.com/en-XUS/Products/Csv`

However if I use requests I get `status_code = 404`.

Any help to point me in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If it's a JS-powered site, then you probably want to look into Selenium.

Comment: I've been warned by better men than myself to avoid that sort of thing. I'm not quite sure what to believe at this point.

Comment: Selenium (or Splinter/Splash/etc.) are useful, especially for a use case such as this. However, you might not need it, either. I haven't taken a look at the site or what it would take to scrape it to get the data you want. I'd venture to guess the price that you're looking for is actually just part of the HTML (and not hidden behind some JS that needs to execute) and you could probably get away with just reading the pages you care about and using BeautifulSoup4 to parse the data. But I don't see a reason to just wholesale discount something - you should evaluate it yourself.

Comment: I have a bit of experience with Selenium and I do agree that it uses more power than a simple request.

I decided (not sure if it's the correct decision) to simply fetch the list of items as seen on the page through csv/exml. 

That is definitely a javascript function. 

You may be right about the price and quantity however.

If I understand you clearly though, you're saying Selenium is just probably my choice here, correct?

Comment: You would first need to work out how to login to their site, otherwise that information is not given. Once logged in you could download the `csv` file using something like `requests.get("http://store.intcomex.com/en-XUS/Products/Csv")`

Comment: @Martin 

True. The `csv` can be taken without login though. One of the issues I'm facing is that I don't know how to convert what is a javascript function (`javascript:PriceListExportCSV('/en-XUS/Products/Csv','query');`) into a simple request such as: `requests.get("http://store.intcomex.com/en-XUS/Products/Csv"‌​)`

Comment: Use the `requests` module then it is great for this, and then a `re` to extract the data you need

Comment: @JoeIddon I have no idea what `javascript:PriceListExportCSV('/en-XUS/Products/Csv','query‌​');` is requesting...

Comment: No you request the raw html of the webpage and then extract the data with a `regex`. You don't need to worry about any `JS` if the info is displayed to you load the page...

Comment: @JoeIddon Not gonna show up using `requests`. May work for price and quantity (once I get my login). What I ended up with instead was `href="javascript:PriceListExportCSV('/en-XUS/Products/Csv','query');">`

Comment: Im sorry, you need to write a clearer more specific question for what you want and then maybe people can help...

Comment: @JoeIddon Thanks for your help. It partially answers my question. In order for me to get the CSV content I would need to run some javascript which isn't converted to html. That's an issue I still face.

Answer (score 0):

After taking the advice of many helpful commenters, I've come to the conclusion that I indeed need to use a browser such as Selenium.

While it may not be the ideal solution, it appears to be only viable one at the moment.

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()

browser.get('http://store.intcomex.com/en-XUS/Products/ByCategory/cpt.allone?r=True')

browser.execute_script("javascript:PriceListExportCSV('/en-XUS/Products/Csv','query');")
```

I'll have to figure it out from here...